# Data is not passing to component in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working in a React Redux project.

My Reducer is like below

**statusReducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_STATUS } from "../firebase/types";

export default (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_STATUS:
      return action.payload || null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My dispatcher is like below

**Status.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { todosRef, authRef, provider } from './firebase';
import { FETCH_STATUS, FETCH_ONESTATUS } from './types.js';

const databaseRef = firebase.firestore();

export const fetchStatus = uid => async dispatch => {
    var data = [];

    databaseRef.collection('status').doc(uid).collection('status').get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var snap = doc.data();
            snap.key = doc.id;
            data.push(snap);
            console.log(data); // I am getting values here
        });

        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_STATUS,
            payload: data,
        });
    });
};
```

My Component is like below

```
import React from "react";
import * as actions from './firebase/Status';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


class Status extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    this.props.fetchStatus(auth.uid);
  };


  renderStatus() {
    const { status } = this.props;
    const data = status ? Object.values(status) : [];

    console.log(status) // I am not getting values here
  }


  render() {
    return (
      //more HTML code
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, status }) => {
  return {
    auth,
    status,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(Status);
```

Comment: What is your reducer state shape/type? It's all over the place. Initial/default is boolean, but then if the payload is falsey it becomes `null`, and the `FETCH_STATUS` action changes it to an array. There is no consistency and this can make your state difficult to work with and debug, due to it's indeterminant nature. In your `Status` component what is invoking `renderStatus` and when? Also, for all practical purposes `componentWillMount` is deprecated, you should instead be using `componentDidMount`. What do your combined reducers look like? Is that the correct state shape, `state.status`?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese for your reply. Actually someone coded all these codes. Could you please guide me to solve the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, we can try, but we'll need a bit more context. Can you update your question to include a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Can we see all of this component code to see when & where `renderStatus` is called, and your reducers and main root reducer so we've a better idea of your state shape?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your `Status.js` file. You're fetching data from firebase and try to dispatch it. But the problem is your program dispatch before getting data form firebase.
So you can use JS Promise for that. Maybe this will help!!!

```
...
const request = snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var snap = doc.data();
        snap.key = doc.id;
        console.log(data); // I am getting values here
  });
});

Promise.all(request).then(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_STATUS,
      payload: data,
  });
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks @dkpradeep for your reply. But similar code is working fine in another component. I am trying to copy another developers code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. The `status.forEach` and `dispatch` both occur in the same scope of the last `.then` block. The code is synchronous, so *all* of `status.forEach` is processed to build up the `data` array that is then dispatched. Your new Promises also *never* resolve so `Promise.all` won't resolve, nor does it update `data`.